# Let a user copy a file to his GoogleDrive account without sharing the source file link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wanna let users copy a file stored in my google drive account without sharing the link of that file (the file is "Public")..
I made this script and deployed it as web app. 
Under "Execute the app as:" i set "user accessing the web app".

```
   function doGet() {
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById("FILE_ID_");
      var name = file.getName();
      var folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
      file.makeCopy(name, folder);
    }
```

but it doesn't work.. Well.. it works only when the user copy and run this script form his account >_>

Do you know what i'm doing wrong? :-/

Comment: I tested your code, and it worked just fine: the (different) user accessing the up was asked for Drive access permission, gave it, and after a few seconds the script finished. Did you put "anyone" in "Who has access to the app"?  Also, something like `return ContentService.createTextOutput('File copied');` would be more user-friendly; otherwise the user is faced with a cryptic semi-error message.

Comment: :'( Well it doesen't work for me.. i don't know why.. I always get this error: "Invalid argument (line 5, file "Code", project "CopyFile")"
The file is 4 GB in size; ther's space in the destination account.. 
I thought the problem was my college account.. so i tried with another account from the same institute.. but nothing changed.. same error..
The webbapp link is: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzCfkiH9zcqBR20plaSbJWtXWs8f8dz8Au5so1QnIj3GXDEaDI/exec
My script Link is: https://script.google.com/d/1gO9Mk7PpVNkw-6OkKUZZh-1l6Z5H2FrtOBrDBU8KZDqnDkcNm62YHV3-/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try with a smaller file, just in case it's indeed a size issue.

Comment: Ok.. now it works O_o
Do u wanna know what the problem was?
The script wasn't updating after deployed as web app...
I just created a new copy of that script.. and it works just fine. And no file size limitation.. TyVM for the help!

Comment: Any updates to a web app script have to be published again, as a new version of the app.